# Fast way to find size of a large s3 bucket I can list and get but don't own?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Lot's of solutions out there to get bucket size via aws s3 ls which is very slow for buckets with lots of objects, and aws cloudwatch which only works for buckets you own.  ([E.g. here](https://serverfault.com/questions/84815/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-an-amazon-s3-bucket/981112#981112))

Is there some way to get a value from aws cloudwatch BucketSizeBytes for a bucket that I can list and get but don't own?

Comment: Sadly, you can't do that.

Comment: I'm not stuck on cloudwatch, but just looking for a reasonably fast solution that doesn't involve listing the entire contents out in some way/shape/form.

Comment: If you know who is the owner, you can ask them for the size, or access to CW. Otherwise, listing is the only way.

Comment: ok thanks -- perhaps then boto3 with parallel processes is the fastest way then since I do not know the owner.